# Sumatoria de numeros

Tags: c#, while, sumatoria

¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa con `while` que imprima la siguiente sumatoria de números y su resultado?

Sumatoria de 1/1 + ½ + 1/3 + ¼ + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 + 1/9 + 1/10 + ... + 1/50.

Resultado: 4.49

```
using System;

namespace sumatoriaDivision
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1 = 1;
            int contador = 1;

            while (contador <= 50)
            {
                Console.Write(num1 +"/"+contador);
                contador++;
                if (contador <= 50)
                {
                    Console.Write(" + ");
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double num = 1;
double sumatoria = 0;
string texto = "";

while(num <= 50)
{
    texto = texto + "1/" + num.ToString() + " + ";
    sumatoria += 1/num;
    num++;
}

//Aquí se eliminan los dos últimos caracteres de texto que son "+ " un espacio y el signo +
texto = texto.Remove(texto.Length - 2);
Console.WriteLine(texto);
Console.WriteLine(sumatoria.ToString());
```

Lo que se hace aquí es que se declara la **variable num** y se inicializa en **1**, posteriormente se empieza a iterar y se hace la sumatoria
desde **1** a **50**, hallando el inverso de la **variable num**.

La **variable texto** va guardando la cadena de la sumatoria.
Posteriormente se imprimen las **variables texto** que contiene la cadena de la sumatoria y también se imprime la **variable sumatoria** que tiene el resultado de la sumatoria.

Comment: solo que es sumatoria y division se divide el uno entre uno despues se suma al uno entre dos y asi susesibamente hasta llegar al uno entre cincuenta, perodon si no aclare eso el resultado debe ser: 4.49

Comment: Amigo eso es exactamente lo que estoy haciendo cuando pongo sumatoria += 1/num, poner += eslo mismo que poner sumatoria = sumatoria+(1/num)

Comment: a perdon entonces algo estoy haciendo mal pq no me sale @japv

Comment: Que te sale entonces

Comment: me da de resultado 1

Comment: Voy a revisar espera

Comment: esta bien, espero

Comment: Ya el error estaba en que num también debe ser de tipo double y no int disculpa

Comment: Una alternativa más eficiente consiste en usar un `StringBuilder` en lugar de string. Otra en imprimir directamente a la consola y borrar los caracteres extra retrocediendo con `\b` y reemplazandolos por espacios.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con este código.

```
int i = 1; // inicializa contador
double sum = 0; // inicializa sumatoria

do
{
   sum += (double)1 / i; // realiza la división como doble y la suma a la sumatoria
   i++; // Incrementa contador
} while (i <= 50); // Mientras que i sea <= 50

Console.WriteLine(sum); // Imprime
Console.ReadLine();
```

En caso que quiera utilizar el while en vez del do-while puede modificarlo así.

```
while (i<=50)
{
    sum += (double)1 / i;
    i++;
}
```

También puede realizarlo con un for

```
for (i=1; i<=50; i++)
{
    sum += (double)1 / i;
}
```